# force sql results to return each date even if it is not in database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(number) AS number, c_date 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE c_date between '11/6/2012' AND '11/12/2012' 
    GROUP BY c_date 
    ORDER BY c_date DESC
```

It will return something like this

```
11    '11/12/2012'
9     '11/9/2012'
10    '11/8/2012'
10    '11/7/2012'
10    '11/6/2012'
```

Now how can I force the return results to include 11/11 and 11/10 with 0 for the *number* rather than skipping over them entirely. Also I cannot create a date table to store the dates.

Comment: "Also I cannot create a date table to store the dates."  Why not?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson only able to query current database

Comment: you can always make a numbers table on the fly with a CTE or temp table.

Comment: @kricket Please see my updated answer... same idea, but the link points to an example using a CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't create a new table, [an alternate approach is to build up a "calendar" CTE](http://blog.celdesigns.com/?p=4).

Next, perform a `LEFT JOIN` from your newly created "calendar" table to `my_table`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(mt.number), 0) AS number, mc.c_date 
FROM 
    my_calendar mc LEFT JOIN
    my_table mt ON mt.c_date = mc.c_date
WHERE mc.c_date between '11/6/2012' AND '11/12/2012' 
GROUP BY mc.c_date 
ORDER BY mc.c_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user defined function that returns a date range. It would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uspDateRange(@MinDate datetime, @Maxdate datetime)
RETURNS @DateRange TABLE ([Date] datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Date datetime

    SET @Date = @MinDate

    WHILE (@Date < @MaxDate)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @DateRange VALUES(@Date)
        SET @Date = DATEADD(day, 1, @Date)
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Now you can select a range to get the range of all days of October 2012:

```
SELECT * FROM uspDateRange('2012-10-01', '2013-11-01')
```

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(number) AS number, c_date 
    FROM my_table t
    INNER JOIN uspDateRange('11/6/2012', '11/12/2012') r ON t.c_date = r.[Date]
    GROUP BY c_date     
    ORDER BY c_date DESC
```